# How to validate Child model (StackedInline) fields based on a value of Parent model's field in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-inline-models

I have following structure.

**models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    PROVIDER1 = "Provider1"
    PROVIDER2= "Provider2"
    PROVIDERS= (
        (PROVIDER1, "Test Provider One"),
        (PROVIDER2, "Test Provider Two"),
    )
    provider = models.CharField(
        choices=PROVIDERS,
        max_length=255,
        default=PROVIDER1,
    )
    # Few more parent fields will be here

class Child(models.Model):
    some_field= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # Few more fields will be here
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

**admin.py**

```
class ChildFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        for form in self.forms:
            if not form.is_valid():
                return  # errors exist, so return

class ChildInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Child
    formset = ChildFormset
    extra = 1
    min_num = 1
    validate_min = True
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False

@admin.register(Parent)
class Parent(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ParentForm
    inlines = [
        ChildInline,
    ]
```

**forms.py**

```
class ParentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = "__all__"

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        # How to access Child model's fields values here to validate them?


    class Media:
        # Custom JS to show/hide provider specific fields/divs
        js = ("js/mycustom.js",)
```

**Requirement:**

When admin user choose **Provider 1** in the Parent I would like to do following

1. Display Child Model's fields (Inline).
2. Validate Child model's fields on submit.

I was able to use custom JavaScript for first requirement (hiding and showing fields).
But for second requirement I am not able to get the Child model's fields into **Parent Form's** `clean()` method or Parent model's chosen `provider` into **ChildFormset's** `clean()` method.

The current validation works irrespective of the option chosen by user for Provider.